# Java cumulative sum program throws NoSuchElement if sum is positive

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that will read a list of integers from a file, and perform a cumulative sum. If at any point, the sum becomes a negative number, then the program will stop and list how many steps it took until the sum became negative.

The only part I am having trouble with is when you have a list where the sum never becomes negative. The program will throw a NoSuchElementException. I have tried placing the if statement that updates the boolean in different locations, and a few other ways of writing this program, but still can't get it to work. Any advice is appreciated.

```
public static boolean negativeSum(Scanner input)
{
    boolean negative = true;
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while(sum >= 0)
    {
        int inputNumber = input.nextInt();
        counter++;
        sum += inputNumber;
        if(sum < 0)
        {
            System.out.println(sum + " after " + counter + " steps");
            negative = true;
        }   

        else
        {
            negative = false;
        }
    }

    if(negative == false)
    {
        System.out.println("no negative sum");
    }

    return negative;
}
```

For example, the list "3 5 5 7 5 -70" will print that the sum was -45 after 6 steps. But the list "1 4 3 5 -6 9 8 6" will throw the exception.

Comment: You are setting `negative = true` on every loop meaning the last value is the only one which matters.

Comment: You keep reading the scanner even if there is no more data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if your scanner has an input before reading from it, otherwise `input.nextInt()` will throw an exception.

To do this, you'll need to call the `hasNextInt()` method on your scanner, which will return `true` or `false` depending on whether there is an integer that can be read.

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    scanner.nextInt();
}
```

In your case, you may want to add it to your while condition, i.e.

```
while (sum > 0 && input.hasNextInt())
```

This will prevent the loop body from executing if there are no numbers left to read.

For more information, check out the [official documentation for the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()).